# Download files in Assets fields

Tags: craft-features

I´m using for the first time Guest Entries plugin to collect some info and some files from users, great! All it´s going great, the site admin will see all the info that the clients sends and the files from each one, but i would like to know if there is a way to download the assets from a specific entry, so keep it simple to download the assets sended by some specific user.

[image]

Something like this plugin does, but it doesn´t work.
https://github.com/Hambrook/AssetLinks

I found this one too, but it downloads the assets of a entire source.
https://github.com/mattstauffer/craftcms-DownloadAssets

Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the javascript of the [asset](https://github.com/Hambrook/AssetLinks/blob/master/resources/js/assetlinks.js) file to something like this and it will work

```
$(function(){
    $(".field .input .elementselect .element:not(.linked)").each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if (!$this.data("url")) { return false; }
        var $a = $("<a class='icon'> </a>")
            .attr("href", $this.data("url"))
            .attr("title", "Download")
            .addClass("download")
            .addClass("sharebtn")
            .addClass("icon")
            .attr('download', $this.data('label'))
            .appendTo($this);
        $this
            .addClass("linked")
            .prepend($a);
    })
});
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!