# Trouble finding the correct path to template in custom module and getting the "Unable to find the template" error

Tags: templating, custom-fieldtype, modules

I've created a custom module trying to implement new field types. I'm using [How to create custom field type in Craft 3](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/30092/how-to-create-custom-field-type-in-craft-3?newreg=87ea4975437740918e6f5b4cf160a7cc) and https://github.com/mmikkel/IncognitoField-Craft3
as reference on how to structure the module.

However, with a barebones version, I cannot seem to get the correct path to my templates. My module structure has the templates at:

```
SalesteamModule/src/templates/_components/fields/_input.twig
```

And the main function is:

```
public function getInputHtml($value, ElementInterface $element = null): string
    {
        // Get our id and namespace
        $id = Craft::$app->getView()->formatInputId($this->handle);
        $namespacedId = Craft::$app->getView()->namespaceInputId($id);

        // Render the input template
        return Craft::$app->getView()->renderTemplate(
            'salesteam-module/_components/fields/_input',
            [
                'name' => $this->handle,
                'value' => $value,
                'field' => $this,
                'id' => $id,
                'namespacedId' => $namespacedId,
            ]
        );
    }
```

App.php

```
return [

    // All environments
    '*'       => [
        'modules'   => [
            'site-module' => [
                'class' => \modules\sitemodule\SiteModule::class,
            ],
            'salesteam-module' => [
                'class' => \modules\salesteammodule\SalesteamModule::class,
            ],
        ],
        'bootstrap' => ['site-module', 'salesteam-module'],
    ],

    // Live (production) environment
    'live'    => [
    ],

    // Staging (pre-production) environment
    'staging' => [
    ],

    // Local (development) environment
    'local'   => [
    ],
];
```

The module is registered as "salesteam-module" in the app config, so I don't think it's a module id thing. And the path I copied the structure of the Incognito plugin I posted above. Although that repo is a plugin, not a module if that makes any difference.

Not sure where to go from here since I've tried a whole slew of different path combinations.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a module and not a plugin, you might need to declare your base template directory in the Module's `__construct` using:

```php
Event::on(View::class, View::EVENT_REGISTER_CP_TEMPLATE_ROOTS, function (craft\events\RegisterTemplateRootsEvent $e) {
    if (is_dir($baseDir = $this->getBasePath() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'templates')) {
        $e->roots[$this->id] = $baseDir;
    }
});
```

See [Andrews's article](https://nystudio107.com/blog/enhancing-a-craft-cms-3-website-with-a-custom-module#2-the-module-class) on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick.